# How to set the properties of a button child elements when it is clicked in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have the following code which is available in all elements of a List and i will like to toggle the Icon active property when the button is clicked preferable using someFunction() method. I need help

```
import React from 'react';
```

export class QuestionsHelpers
{
    username = '';

```
constructor(username)
{
    this.username = username;
}


 static renderQuestionContent(questionData, props, stateHandler)
{
   /...///code
   let status = questionData.user_liked === "1";
   <Button transparent onPress={()=>someFunction()}>
<Icon active={status} name="thumbs-up"/>
<Text>Vote</Text>
```

```
}
```

}

below is where i call the method renderQuestion

```
questionList(props)
{
    return this.state.data.map(function (questionData, index)
        {
            return QuestionsHelpers.renderQuestionContent(questionData, props, null)
        }
    );
}
```

and then the whole thing is inside the render method

```
 render()
{
    let data = <View/>;
    if(this.state.data !== [])
    {
        data = this.questionList(this.props, null);
    }
    let spinner = this.state.loading === true?  (<Spinner color='#FF7F00'/>) : (<Button title='Load more' onPress={()=>this.loadInitialState().done()}/>);
    return (
        <Content>

            {data}
            {spinner}
        </Content>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use state for the button somewhere. For example:

```
class Doge extends React.Component { 
  state = {
    status: false,
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Button transparent={() => this.setState({ status: !this.state.status})>
        <Icon active={this.state.status} name="thumbs-up" />
        <Text>Vote</Text>
      </Button>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: i am sorry i did not mention but the button is present in  all elements in a list. Its like a newsfeed where and the button is like a like button

Comment: What library are you using? There should be a `clicked` property on the button, which you can use if you don't care about saving the state anywhere.

Comment: Its a native base button, I want to toggle the Icon active prop when the button is clicked

Comment: If you have all the elements in a list then just have something like `statuses = []` in your state, and `<Icon active{this.state.status[key]) />` when you render.

Comment: You need to add more code if you want a better answer, I think.

Comment: Thanks i edited the question is saving all the states efficient??

Comment: Just store the `clicked` status on the `data` object you already have in state, and use that to set the button clicked or not.